# How can I get the whole String printed out and not only the single character?

Tags: java, stringbuilder, lowercase

Here is my problem: I'm building a `StringBuilder` and I built a `toLowerCase()` method which only gives me back a single character and not the whole string.

```
 public MyStringBuilder1 toLowerCase() {
      String newStr = "";
      for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) >= 'A' && s.charAt(i) <= 'Z') {
          newStr = newStr + (char)(s.charAt(i) + 32) + "";
        }
      }
      return new MyStringBuilder1(newStr);
    }

 public static void main(String[] args) { 
      // Create a MyStringBuilder1 object 
      MyStringBuilder1 str1 = new MyStringBuilder1("Radixsort"); 
      // Display string as lowercase 
      System.out.println("\nString to lower case: " + str1.toLowerCase());
  }
```

Comment: What is your input? And what is there inside method MyStringBuilder1?

Comment: Hint: you're ignoring non-uppercase characters. Your debugger is your friend. Learn to use it. It's super-easy, and will help you find some trivial issues like this one. Learn to use it now. You'll avoid wasting days and days.

Comment: What is your construction and how do you get result?

Comment: @gauravJeswani                                                                                                                          ```public static void main(String[] args) {
  // Create a MyStringBuilder1 object
  MyStringBuilder1 str1 = new MyStringBuilder1("Radixsort");

  // Display string as lowercase
  System.out.println("\nString to lower case: " + str1.toLowerCase());´´´´

Answer (score 1):

you can use `toString()` on `StringBuilder` in order to return `String`

but you aren't leveraging the `StringBuilder` power, when it come to long strings the concatenation of them might take great amount of resources

in order to concatenate strings, one string is copied to a new slot in the memory and then the next one

`StringBuilder` gives an List like behaviour, you can append char dynamically to the stringBuilder with much less effort

so instead of

```
newStr = newStr + (char)(s.charAt(i) + 32) + "";
```

you better use

```
stringBuilder.append((char)(s.charAt(i) + 32))
```

suggest to read the following [tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stringbuilder-class-in-java-with-examples/)

***keep in mind***, the significant performance gain will increase with the string length, but on short strings, the compiler optimization will yield much better performance